# ios7 xcode 5 GM: color of UIBarButtonItem and selected UISegmentedControl part on iOS 6 device keep default color

Tags: iphone

i'm porting now ios6 app to ios7 sdk (with Xcode 5 and mavericks) and i tried to change UIBarButtonItem color, here is what i try to do:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor
```

- make changes color for bar but not for items

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

- doesn't work, same wrong color

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

- doesn't work, same wrong color

```
    UIBarButtonItem *close = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close",@"") 
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                    action:@selector(closeAddressBook:)];

           close.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

- doesn't work, same wrong color

```
  for self.filterSegment.tintColor =  [UIColor greenColor] where UISegmentedControl *filterSegment;
```

i see unselected segment with correct color, but selected segment is a same wrong color.

any ideas?

Comment: I have been trying to do the same thing with my UIBarButtonItem and my back button also, and it is not working for me either.

Comment: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor]; changed my button to green.

Comment: @Smick are u on Xcode 5 GM and ios7 build and running on ios6 device?

Comment: Yes, I tested in another view, it seems to work with buttons you add manually, but not those that appear but default - such as the back button in a nag. controller. I do recall apple mention there is a new way to change these, and that change filters through all your views. Check out WWDC 2013 Video - Customizing Your App’s Appearance for iOS 7.

Comment: @Smick try to add them manually and look.

Comment: @user170317 if you add them manually you need to set them individually. See my comment above.

Answer (score 15):

Figured out what needs to be done, thanks to WWDC 2013 - Customizing Your App’s Appearance for iOS 7.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This will filter down into the other views in your app, so place on initial screen, and if you push to the next screen you will see that the back button is also red.

To change the navigation bar colour use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

If you are making your app work for devices less than iOS7, you should check it responds to the selector

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]) {

}
```

Comment: this is not a solution, bcs i have troubles with running on IOS 6 with iOS 7 SDK, of course barTintColor will crashed on iOS 6....

Comment: @user170317 yes it will crash, hence the reason for the if statement at the end of my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't check against version.  You should be checking against functionality: if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]) { ... }

Comment: This doesn't work for me when an app is using the base iOS6 sdk but runs on iOS7

Comment: the selector would be setBarTintColor: not barTintColor, wouldn't it? -rrh

Answer (score 10):

For iOS7 this code works for me when I wish to change the colour of an individual `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
[barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[barButtonItem];
```

Comment: Huge thanks.  In iOS6, you just set the tintColor.  In iOS7, you set TitleTextAttributes with attribute NSForegroundColorAttributeName.

Comment: This works perfectly. Way less hacky than setting the tintColor on the same UIWindow.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to set the `tintColor` property on your app's `UIWindow` instance instead. If you've got a standard 'accent' colour you're using throughout your app, this will tint every control in the app with that colour.

Comment: uiwindow not support to set tint color, can u please edit answer with more details?

Comment: Yes it does, `UIWindow` inherits from `UIView` which declares `tintColor` as a property: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tintColor

Comment: @rpowell, I'm not sure why but I've tried setting the UIWindow.tintColor in the app delegate but it doesn't do anything.  Not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** In `iOS 7`, the `tintColor` property is no longer used for setting the color of the bar. Instead, use the `barTintColor` property to change the background color.You can insert the below code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of `AppDelegate.m`.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

**2-** In iOS 7, all bar buttons are borderless. The back button is now a chevron plus the title of the previous screen (or just displays ‘Back’ as the button title if the title of the previous screen is nil). To tint the back button, you can alter the `tintColor` property, which provides a quick and simple way to skin your app with a custom color. Below is a sample code snippet:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

This is the way to set the color for the backbutton.

Just a note for ppl who developed the app using IOS 6, we used the above code to set the Nav Bar Color, so by mistake if you did not remove the previous setting you will not see the change to the back button.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not removing the previous setting?

Answer (score -2):

I finally figured out the way to solve this problem.
After setting the button, you need to wait 5-7 ms (in case of iPhone 5s).

```
UIBarButtonItem *button=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]...

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=button;

[button performSelector:@selector(setTintColor:) withObject:[UIColor blueColor] afterDelay:0.1];
```

You shouldn't set the color before setting `rightBarButtonItem`. It should work for both iOS 6 & 7.