# IOS7 statusbar difference between simulator and iphone

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I have created a custom white image ( 640 x 128 pixel ) and set it as background for the navigation bar using:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIImage* navBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarWhite.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarBackgroundImage  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My goal is to have both navigation and statusbar with a white background.
As far as I test it in the simulator everything looks fine, means both nav and statusbar have a white background.
As soon as I run it on my iPhone 4S the statusbar turns light gray..

Additional info:

UINavigationBar Style UIBarStyleDefault Translucent

UIStatusBarStyleDefault

I am using navigation controllers.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817626/ios7-xcode-5-gm-color-of-uibarbuttonitem-and-selected-uisegmentedcontrol-part-o/18837995#18837995

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074365/status-bar-and-navigation-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7